# Building a System.Net surrogate DLL under MonoTouch - avoiding a "Friend access" clash?

Tags: xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

In order to get Portable Library Projects v2 working in MonoTouch, I'm currently jumping through a small number of hoops.

One of them is that I'm building a forwarding DLL for System.Net methods (see some explanation in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-portable-library-tools-for.html)

However, I'm having some problems actually generating a DLL with the right name - because if I generate it as `System.Net` then I get an error during build of:

> Error CS0281: Friend access was granted to `System.Net,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', but the output assembly is named`
>   System.Net, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Try adding a reference to `System.Net,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or change the output assembly name to
>   match it (CS0281) (System.Net.Touch)

I do have a way around this - generating the file under a different name and then manually renaming it afterwards. But I'd prefer to avoid this step if I can.

Can anyone suggest a way to avoid this error while still generating an assembly called System.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of research on this, it seems that the only way to do this within a solution is the workaround I already had:

> I do have a way around this - generating the file under a different name and then manually renaming it afterwards. But I'd prefer to avoid this step if I can.

Hopefully this won't be needed soon anyway - as we have official Xamarin PCL support under production right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps. I was able to take your code and build a delay signed System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e in Visual Studio 2010. Then successfully used that DLL to build a simple application (One PCL + One MonoTouch) to compile and run in both VS/Windows and Xamarin/Mac.

Comment: Thanks - it does help - but I can't mark it as the answer as it doesn't compile the DLL itself in Xamarin Studio. Will answer with what I did and with a 'impossible' answer.

Comment: @Stuart, no I wasn't expecting you to accept as answer, was trying to workaround the problem and I thought I should share what I found. Maybe I should have added a comment instead (not an active stackoverflower). That being said, for time being (before the Xamarin releases PCL support), how about creating a separate github repo and making a binary package? The binary can be used by MvvmCross or any other projects want to take advantage of PCL in Monotouch development.